# Recovering the Variance when Arbitrary Function is applied to Distribution

Tags: distributions, variance, function

Say I have some arbitrary distribution for the value of $a$. I know its mean $\mu_a$ and I know its standard deviation $\sigma_a$.

Say I also have some arbitrary relation between $a$ and $b$. I know the function $a = f(b)$ which takes $b$ to $a$.

If I want to know the mean of $b$, I can solve $\mu_a = f(b)$ for $b$ to obtain $\mu_b$.

How can I obtain $\sigma_b$?

The following *Mathematica* code illustrates the problem (using a specific distribution, function, mean and standard deviation):

```
myMean = 1.2;
mySTD = 0.34;
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[myMean,mySTD],a],{a,0,2}]
```

[image]

```
myF[b_] := (1-b)^2
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[myMean,mySTD],myF[b]],{b,-1,3}]
```

[image]

```
Solve[myF[b]==myMean,b]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe $a=f(b)=log(b)$ is often used. Surely, there are methods to obtain the variance.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Clearly this was based on a miscomprehension. In hindsight I know better. But the question is not ill-posed, nor inappropriate for this forum.

Comment: Though this does not work for arbitrary functions, it does for some specific ones. Related concepts: [Generalised linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) and [Polynomial chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_chaos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work in general, it doesn't work for the mean either. For a simple example, let's use $X \sim \text{Norm}(0, 1)$ and $f(x) = x^2$.

Then the squared of the expection of $X$ is zero, but if you calculate the mean of the squares, you clearly get a different, positive number. To be specific, $X^2$ is distributed as a Chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom and it's expectation is 1.

Let's say a sample has a mean of exactly 1, we think it's because of the square so we solve the equation and think that the original mean should be 1 or -1. But it was zero. To say, this method doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. In the worst case, I could always simulate a large number of $x$'s from the first distribution, then apply the inverse of $f$ to that list of datapoints and finally determine the mean and std of the mapped data. Would that not give me the correct values? If so, why wouldn't there be an analytical method?

Comment: It is very much not true that you can just solve $\mu_a = f(b)$ to obtain $\mu_b$ for an arbitrary relation $f$. In fact, it's hard to come up with a situation where this would give you an approximation of $\mu_b$, except where $f$ is the identity function. The example I give is a concrete instance of this not working. In short, no, that doesn't give you the correct values. In your example, you get two b's, but a distribution has only one mean. So even though these values correspond to the bumps, it's unclear what you are getting at, to me.